# Can't show array values multi query from the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to show array values using each month a year from the controller but is not showing anything.

Here is the information and demo:

```
CREATE TABLE player_scores (id INT,name text,date_score date,goals INT );
CREATE TABLE months (id INT,name text );

INSERT INTO player_scores VALUE
 ( 1, 'PIZARRO'   , '2015-01-02', 4),
 ( 2, 'ROBBEN'    , '2015-02-24', 2),
 ( 3, 'RIBERY'    , '2015-03-02', 4),
 ( 4, 'GOTZE'     , '2015-04-24', 2),
 ( 5, 'NEIWER'    , '2015-05-02', 4),
 ( 6, 'DANTE'     , '2015-06-24', 2),
 ( 7, 'LEWANDOSKI', '2015-07-02', 4),
 ( 8, 'RAFINHA'   , '2015-07-02', 4),
 ( 9, 'GUARDIOLA' , '2015-11-02', 3);

INSERT INTO months VALUE
 ( 1, 'jan'),
 ( 2, 'feb'),
 ( 3, 'mar'),
  ...      
 ( 12,'dec');
```

Here is the controller:

```
def germany_world_cup
   @months= Month.all

   ## THIS LINE WILL REPEAT THE QUERY 12 TIMES FOR EACH MONTH JANUARY TO DECEMBER 
   @months.each do |m|
      @query = PlayerScore.find_by_sql("SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM player_scores WHERE YEAR(date_score)=2015 AND MONTH(date_score)='#[m.id}' ")
   end
end
```

Here is the view with the problem (is not showing values):

```
<% @query.each do |q| %> 
  <%= q.count_all %>  ### IS SHOWING only 0 as result
<% end %>
```

Here is my log actually working but is not showing in the view:

```
select count(*) as count_all from player_scores where month(date_score)=1 and year(date_score)=2015
select count(*) as count_all from player_scores where month(date_score)=2 and year(date_score)=2015
...
select count(*) as count_all from player_scores where month(date_score)=12 and year(date_score)=2015
```

According to rails sintaxis to show values from controller is

```
<% @var.each do |v| %>
   <%= v.column_name %>
<% end %>
```

I tried this code to inspect values but got nothing:

```
<%= @query.inspect %>  ### I got " [#] " as result
```

I tried this code:

```
<% @query[0].each do |q| %> 
  <%= q.count_all %>   ### I GOT THIS ERROR "undefined method `each' "
<% end %>
```

I want to show valus from arrays in the controller

Please somebody can tell me to show values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your loop will repeat the query 12 times, but each time it loops it just overwrites the `@query` instance variable

Comment: So is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You can do `@queries = []` then do your loop but assign the result to the queries variable, so you're putting them all into an array e.g. `@queries << PlayerScore.find_by_sql(my_query)` in your loop

Comment: Why not do `PlayerScore.select("Month(date_score) as in_month, Count(id) as count_all").where("Year(date_score)=2015").group("Month(date_score)").order("Month(date_score)")`. This will execute 1 query and allow you iterate appropriately giving access to `in_month` and `count_all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to avoid the `@query` variable overwrite is to use `#map`:

```
@query = @months.map do |m|
   PlayerScore.find_by_sql("SELECT count(*) AS count_all FROM player_scores WHERE YEAR(date_score)=2015 AND MONTH(date_score)='#[m.id}' ")
end
```

Comment: @EzioAuditore yes, but that is not quite ruby approach ;)

Comment: Thanks it was a good advice, it worked for me +1 for your help.